# Change how the Subtotal Price in cart being calculated

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the subtotal price in wooocommerce cart. If particular variations product containing more than 1 Quantity i want to change the subtotal price on cart. For example if product A have price 12 then users update the Quantity into 2 i want to show subtotal same 12. If Quantity is 3 then i want to show subtotal 24. Every time Quantity increasing i want to minus the regular price of product from subtotal. My current code is following its not working for me.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'misha_recalculate_price' );

function misha_recalculate_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
     $product_ids = array(2697);

    $quantity = 0;


    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {

        if( in_array( $value['variation_id'], $product_ids )  ) {


            $quantity += $value['quantity'];

        }


    }

    if( $quantity > 1 ) {
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $hash => $value ) {



            if( in_array( $value['variation_id'], $product_ids ) ) {

                $newprice = echo $value['line_total'] - $value['data']->get_regular_price();

                 $cart_object->subtotal -= $value['data']->get_regular_price();

                $value['data']->set_price( $newprice );

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you include the reason as to why you're doing this?

Comment: The reason is want to give product A as free gift when cart quantity more than 25 doller. So when Product B added into cart Then product A also added to cart automatically when cart total meet more than 25 doller. Also when user purchase Product A more than 2 or 3 qty at that time cart total meet 25 so i want to give 1 qty as free at that time.

Comment: if you want it as free then setting the price to 0 would be it right? like `$value['data']->set_price(0);`? that is for product A

Comment: At that time its not changing the subtotal value that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, I see a few problems with your code..

First is the `echo` in `$newprice = echo $value['line_total'] - $value['data']->get_regular_price();`
Please remove the `echo`.

Second, I think you are better of using the "after", that is `woocommerce_after_calculate_totals`. You are using the "before", that is after your code runs, `line_total` will be changed.

Comment: Let me check then after i will inform you

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: you should be more specific on what's not working... what are you getting when you say it's not working...

Comment: Sorry the subtotal is not changing for me

Comment: when adding product A with qty 3 into cart product price is showing 12.95 and subtotal showing 38.85. Actually i want to show subtotal is 25.9. That means i need to minus 1 qty price from that subtotal

Comment: check if the variation_id is really `2697`. You can try putting `print_r($cart_object->get_cart());` to check

Comment: Yes variation_id have no issue

Comment: I've used your [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/sJi5kkUz) as is, and it's working... I've only changed the `$product_ids = array(42);` to reflect on my test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102151/discussion-between-developerme-and-reigel).

Comment: Please send your cart screen shot

Comment: any solution ? i need that too. @Reigel